# How to pass session variables via the URL in ColdFusion 10 for use in Flash AS2?

Tags: session, coldfusion, actionscript-2, session-cookies, coldfusion-10

I have a client with some old Flash functionality (AS2). The SWF allows the user to upload an image. However a new session is being started when the upload script is called. I have added the CFID, CFTOKEN and JSESSIONID to the URL as I did in the past to maintain the session but I believe you cannot do this anymore with CF10, if this is correct can anyone point me in the right direction of how I would accomplish maintaining the session for the upload?

This has a note about CF 10 - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1178420

Comment: It appears as though that functionality is still supported in CF10. Not sure why it is not working for you. Have you enabled session management for your application/server? For some reason Adobe has two versions of their CF10 documentation online - [reference 1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cbf) and [reference 2](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Managing+the+client+state)

Comment: Thanks Miguel-F.

I've had a look at the documentation and as I'm using J2EE session varibles I'm just passing the jsessionid. But for some reason (only on firefox) the session is recreated and the URL parameters ignored. Firefox works fine on ColdFusion 9 so I'm stumped.